# Not connect with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, database-connection

I have 2 connection string in 2 file connect.php connect to 2 mysql database on 2 server.

File dbconnect1:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('sv1','root','123456') or dir("No connect");
mysql_select_db('db1')or dir("not connect database");
mysql_query("SET charactor_set_results=utf8",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

File dbconnect2:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('sv1','root','123456') or dir("No connect");
mysql_select_db('db2')or dir("not connect database");
mysql_query("SET charactor_set_results=utf8",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

When I include in file php and exercute query it not show result.
One of 2 connection string not work. Why?

Comment: echo `mysql_error($conn)` and see what error it throws

Comment: please use `die()` instead of `dir()`

Comment: it show table1.db1 not exits or table1.db2 not exits

Comment: Please add the code of the query that is actually failing. Where you are trying to "show result".

Comment: I think it is because you use the same variable $conn for both DB connections. Replace it with $conn2 for example in the dbconnect2.php file

Comment: it work normally with singer query but  it not working when i include 2 file dbconnect in 1 file php

Comment: but i try it on localhost it work nomally but on server it not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you use the same variable $conn for both DB connections. Replace it with $conn2 for example in the dbconnect2.php file. At the moment your first connection get overwritten by the second connection. This is because you do them one after another.

Plus you have to put TRUE for the fourth paramether in mysql_connect() function in order to start a new connection to the same DB server. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

File dbconnect2:

```
<?php
$conn2 = mysql_connect('sv1','root','123456', TRUE) or die("No connect");
mysql_select_db('db2', $conn2)or die("not connect database");
mysql_query("SET charactor_set_results=utf8", $conn2);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn2);
?>
```

Plus you have to point which MySQL connection you want to use in mysql_select_db() function(s) and mysql_query() function(s).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the second db connection variable say $conn2 and also use the connection statement as follows:

```
$conn2 = mysql_connect('sv1','root','123456', TRUE) or die("No connect");
```

Where the 4th parameter has to pass as TRUE.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: it must be die() not dir() :)

Comment: Yes,   Thanks:)  Yasen Zhelev

Comment: $querry = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(pay_cards.price) as thanhtien, skycity_account_vmg.providers.PartnerID AS partnerid, skycity_account_vmg .providers.keyword as mkd, pay_cards.provider_code as nhamang,pay_cards.price as menhgia,         COUNT(pay_cards.game_id) as soluong,pay_cards.game_id as gameid FROM pay_cards JOIN skycity_account_vmg.providers on providers.provider_id=pay_cards.provider_id where (DATE_FORMAT(requested_at,'%Y-%m-%d')>='".$bd."' AND DATE_FORMAT(requested_at,'%Y-%m-%d')<='".$kt."') AND pay_cards.price is not null group by menhgia
ORDER BY menhgia DESC") this is my query

Comment: does this query wrong? But i try it on localhost it work nomally but on server is not.

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev The query is not readable in this comment box. If this is working in local, query syntax must me correct. If the above solution works, can you mark it as answer so that others can also refer this.